# Performing calculations between rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I’m trying to figure out how to make a calculation across (or between?) rows. I’ve tried looking this up but clearly my Google-Fu is not strong today, because I’m just not finding the right search terms.

Here is a super simplified example of the type of data I’m trying to deal with:

```
mydf <- data.frame(pair = rep(1,2), 
                   participant = c("PartX", "PartY"), 
                   goalsAtt = c(6, 3), 
                   goalsScr = c(2, 3))
```

We have data on how many "goals" a participant attempted and how many they actually scored, and lets say I want to know about their "defensive" ability. Now essentially what I want to do is `mutate()` two new columns called… let’s say `saved` and `missed`, where `saved` would be the goals attempted by the opposite participant minus the goals scored by them, and `missed` would just be goals scored by the opposite participant. So obviously participant X would have saved 0 and missed 3, and participant Y will have saved 4 and missed 2.

Now obviously this is a stupid simple example, and I’ll have like 6 different “goal” types to deal with and 2.5k pairs to go through, but I’m just having a mental block about where to start with this.

Amateur coder here, and Tidyverse style solutions are appreciated.

Comment: is there some code you've tried? Are the two rows independent observations or does the `pair` variable connect them? If so can only 2 teams be paired?

Comment: If there are always only two participants, then this can be rather straight-forward. If there are ever more than two, however, your comparisons of "saved" and such become a bit more complex. Would this be grouped by `$pair`, where there are always exactly two rows per unique pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so let's assume that `pair` can only be for 2 teams. Here's a `tidyverse` solution where we first set an index number for position within a group and then subtract for goals saved. Something similar for goals missed.

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>% 
  group_by(pair) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(goalsSaved = if_else(id == 1,
                              lead(goalsAtt) - lead(goalsScr),
                              lag(goalsAtt) - lag(goalsScr))) %>% 
  mutate(goalsMissed = if_else(id == 1,
                               lead(goalsScr),
                               lag(goalsScr)))

# A tibble: 2 x 7
# Groups:   pair [1]
   pair participant goalsAtt goalsScr    id goalsSaved goalsMissed
   <dbl> <fct>          <dbl>    <dbl> <int>      <dbl>       <dbl>
 1     1 PartX              6        2     1          0           3
 2     1 PartY              3        3     2          4           2
```

Comment: Thanks @nycrefugee thats exactly what i was looking for. This is essentially what i was thinking about, I just didn't realise `row_number()` indexes row position in the grouped variable, i assumed it would only use its relative position in the entire dataframe, which is why i never thought this would work, plus i've never used `lead()` and `lag()` before.