# Accessing previous rows to make a calculation in a current row in R

Tags: r

I have data that I need to make calculations within sub-groups of rows. Specifically, I am calculating the nitrogen (N) recovery efficiency of crops between different field treatments. This requires finding the difference in N uptake of crops (totN) between a plot with a given amount of N applied (Nrate) and the control plot with 0 N applied, then dividing by the Nrate.

This is how the data looks for just one year:

```
year drain Nrate  totN 
2016 C         0   190 
2016 C       100   220 
2016 C       200   230 
2016 N         0   130 
2016 N       100   200 
2016 N       200   220
```

I have gotten this far, thanks to [Performing calculations between rows in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54875227/performing-calculations-between-rows-in-r), but I am not sure how to reference the control row (Nrate = 0) within the sub-group each row is in.

This is where I am:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(year=c(2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016),
                 drain=c("C","C","C","N","N","N"),
                 Nrate=c(0,100,200,0,100,200),
                 totN=c(190,220,230,130,200,220))

df %>%
  group_by(year,drain) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(RE = ifelse(id != 1,
                     (totN - <the totN where Nrate=0 for same year and drain>) / Nrate,
                     NA))
```

This is what I expect to get:

```
year drain Nrate  totN  RE
2016 C         0   190  NA
2016 C       100   220  0.3  #(220-190)/100
2016 C       200   230  0.2  #(230-190)/200
2016 N         0   130  NA
2016 N       100   200  0.7  #(200-130)/100
2016 N       200   220  0.45 #(220-130)/200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may subset the 'totN' by indexing or if it is already ordered, use `first(totN)`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(year, drain) %>% 
   mutate(RE = na_if((totN - totN[Nrate == 0])/Nrate, "NaN")) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
#   year drain Nrate  totN    RE
#  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  2016 C         0   190 NA   
#2  2016 C       100   220  0.3 
#3  2016 C       200   230  0.2 
#4  2016 N         0   130 NA   
#5  2016 N       100   200  0.7 
#6  2016 N       200   220  0.45
```

Comment: Thank you very much!